# How detailed is the Application Insights telemetry using Docker hosted in Azure Container Instances

Tags: azure, docker, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights, azure-container-instances

When I deployed my app to Azure App Service I got quite awesome telemetry out of the box.

Some of the telemetry data is generated by the App Service itself, some of it by my ASP.NET Core app that is using Application Insights logging.

As a result I could find out slow http requests, all application and IIS logs related to the request and see a nice chart showing where the time was spent, e.g. waiting for a SQL query or some http call.

I wonder how much of this telemetry can I get if I decide to go with Azure Container Instances.

Answer (score 1):

The telemetry collected from the application itself using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore SDK- you'd pretty much everything of that irrespective of where app is runnning - vm or container or app service.

Answer (score -1):

from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/docker

When you run the Application Insights image on your Docker host, you get these benefits:

- Lifecycle telemetry about all the containers running on the host - start, stop, and so on.
- Performance counters for all the containers. CPU, memory, network usage, and more.
- If you installed Application Insights SDK for Java in the apps running in the containers, all the telemetry of those apps will have additional properties identifying the container and host machine. So for example, if you have instances of an app running in more than one host, you can easily filter your app telemetry by host.

Comment: Please note that this is a deprecated approach.

Comment: It is not recommended to start using this approach for new applications.

Comment: I can see that we need to use Azure Monitor for containers now. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/container-insights-overview